Unable to use GPU for running python script from inside the Notebook
I am using a Jupyter notebook on Google Colab Pro and have activated GPU support via "Change runtime type." Despite this, when I execute my Python script within the notebook cell using the below command, the model training defaults to using the CPU:
!python main.py

Also if I check for cuda availability in notebook, then it shows that the GPU is available. I use the below snippet for the check:
# Check if GPU is available
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    device = torch.device("cuda")
    print("GPU is available and will be used.")
else:
    device = torch.device("cpu")
    print("GPU is not available. Using CPU instead.")


Question: Could someone assist me in executing this Python script in the notebook with GPU support? Are there any solutions to enable this?
Below is the screenshot of the code:

I am not passing any variables from notebook to that python script main.py. Hence I dont need to necessarily use "run -i ...". I am setting torch.device to cuda inside the main.py. But its taking the cpu option. Below is the code I used inside main.py:
self.device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
How do I make sure that this is set to "cuda:0" for GPU access inside the script?

Your screenshot made it look like you were. But I'm testing some myself and I see this works with gpu as long as already turned on in runtime. It errors out because it wants multiple but it at least sees GPU. And it seems to work better with !python vs. %run, which is odd. I cannot determine why !python gets to x_train shape: (60000, 28, 28, 1) and listing the number of train and test samples, whereas %run doesn't. Maybe Colab feeds back the stdout differently.

 So it seems with Colab !python is fine in this context. I tested and the %run -i stuff will work in Colab if you ever need it for developing code.

Hi Wayne, I could resolve this issue. I am using Flower framework for Decentralized Training and there is an internal parameter in my code which was disabling the GPU usage. That parameter is meant for allocating proportion of GPU to each client. Thanks for your help.

Please add an update to the bottom of your post detailing those details. Otherwise others will come read your title and look at your post and think it pertains to them.
